Weird bars under and over font-awesome CSS
I'm getting this weird bars over and under the font awesome icon, I have tried removing the borders, margin, padding and even making the background transparent, none of them seem to work.

I have the following CSS applied
.shade {
  background-color: #00061ace;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.shade-btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: white;
}

button.shade-btn span {
  background-color: #00061ace;
}

for the html
<div class="shade">
  <button type="button" id="update-list" class="shade-btn">
      <span class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"></span>
  </button>
</div>

Here is a codepen example to work with.
Thank you :)

Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Can you try adding a text-decoration:none; to the buttons

What style properties you see via the Inspector panel in the browser? Most probably some other styling is inherited

I have added the minimal reproducible code along with the codepen link of the same. My sincere apologies for missing the div element.

@AdamBasha I tried using text-decorations: none; but it doesn't work

@CBroe Sure I have updated.

This is simply a white background color of the button (coming from the UA stylesheet) showing on the top and bottom, because your span element is not as high as the button itself. Either increase the height of the span element, so that it covers the full button height - or set background-color: transparent (or background: none) for the button.

I see its just the background color of the button. Thank you so much @CBroe for the explanation, it totally worked!

It is the span element. It produces a minimal gap around it because it is an inline element. Setting it to display: block oder inline-block will remove the "borders". More information about this topic here
